# C int to binary

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I am making a c program, that has to later run on the raspberry pi, the program gets an argument from the command line, determines if its value is between 0 and 15. If so convert it to binary and return it.

and if not, just printing an error message.

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int convert(int dec)
{
    if (dec == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (dec % 2 + 10 * convert(dec / 2));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // argc is number of arguments given including a.out in command line
    // argv is a list of string containing command line arguments

    printf("the number is:%s \n", argv[2]);

    int v = atoi(argv[2]);
    int bin = 0;

    if(v >= 0 && v <= 15){
        printf("Correct input");
        bin = convert(v);
        printf("Binary is: %s \n", convert(v));
    }
    else{
        printf("Inorrect input, number cant be accepted");
    }
}
```

when I compile this online [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler), with `$./a.out 1`, I get the following error:

> the number is:1
>   Segmentation fault

input:

```
./a.out 12
```

expected output:

```
the number is:12
Correct inputBinary is: 1100
```

The convert method I found on stackoverflow.

***edit my new answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int convert(int dec)
{
    if (dec == 0)
    {
        printf("Base c\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Rec call\n");
        return ((dec % 2) + 10 * convert(dec / 2));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // argc is number of arguments given including a.out in command line
    // argv is a list of string containing command line arguments

    int v = atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("the number is:%d \n", v);


    int bin = 0;

    if(v >= 0 && v <= 15){
        printf("Correct input \n");
        bin = convert(v);
        printf("Binary is: %d \n", bin);
    }
    else{
        printf("Inorrect input, number cant be accepted");
    }
}
```

the out put:

```
the number is:3                                                                                                                    
Correct input                                                                                                                      
Rec call                                                                                                                           
Rec call                                                                                                                           
Base c                                                                                                                             
Binary is: 11
```

how ever the binary has to be 0011 for 3. this part is what I am working on now.

Comment: I would guess `argv[2]` ==> `argv[1]`

Comment: well... 1. index in C start by 0 so use `argv[1]`, 2. what do you mean by convert to binary ???

Comment: The `int` already is binary, so returning `int` from `convert` makes no sense. You mean convert to a string of one and zeros?

Comment: He means a function `f: int -> int` such that the decimal representation of `f(x)` is the same than the binary representation of `x`

Comment: @Bromind ah, I see it is recursive.

Comment: Please show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: input: `./a.out 12`, expected output: `the number is:12Correct inputBinary is: 1100` with a newline after "`12`".

Comment: @Bromind please [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_

Comment: its not *my* question, I don't think I can edit it :-) [addendum] my bad, its not my question, but I actually can edit it

Comment: @Bromind oh sorry, I didn't notice.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the wrong format specifier here:

```
printf("Binary is: %s \n", convert(v));
```

`convert` returns an `int` but `%s` requires a `char*`.

You need:

```
printf("Binary is: %d \n", convert(v));
                // ^----
```

And the first argument passed to the program is `argv[1]`, not `argv[2]`

Therefore:

```
printf("the number is:%s \n", argv[1]);
                                // ^----
```

and

```
int v = atoi(argv[1]);
               // ^----
```

Comment: `convert` is recursive.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, it is recursive, so what?

Comment: As commented by @Bromind, each power of 10 represents a binary digit `0` or `1`.

Comment: Conclusion: the `convert` function is correct and the answer addresses all problems the OP experienced.

Comment: thanks I made some improvements, however, the binary is not of the correct length.

Comment: @S.N what do you mean by "not of the correct length? Can you show an example of what you get and what you expect?

Comment: @S.N as your numbers go from 0 to 15, you maybe you just need `%04d` instead of `%d`, this will display the number with 4 digits including leading zeros if necessary

Comment: @MichaelWalz I accepted your answer and thanks a lot again.

Comment: @MichaelWalz only thiong I dont undertsnad is this, why has to be argv[2] but not argv[1], this part I really dont get and I dont know how to make that on rasbperrypi

Comment: @MichaelWalz so the vlue of bin for input 3 is 11 not 0011, but in the print section it makes it to 0011, but if I want to use that binary somewhere else its still 11. is there any otehr way that I fix this issue?

Comment: @S.N the number `11` is the number `11`. `0011` or `0000011` are just different representations of the same number. Maybe you want to work with strings instead of numbers? Concerning `argv[2]` look at the updated answer, it is of course `argv[1]` and not `argv[2]`, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer to my question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int convert(int dec)
{
    if (dec == 0)
    {
        printf("Base c\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Rec call\n");
        return ((dec % 2) + 10 * convert(dec / 2));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // argc is number of arguments given including a.out in command line
    // argv is a list of string containing command line arguments

    int v = atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("the number is:%d \n", v);


    int bin = 0;

    if(v >= 0 && v <= 15){
        printf("Correct input \n");
        bin = convert(v);
        printf("Binary is: %04d \n", bin);
    }
    else{
        printf("Inorrect input, number cant be accepted");
    }
}
```

the input: `$./a.out 3`
the output:

```
the number is:3                                                                                                                    
Correct input                                                                                                                      
Rec call                                                                                                                           
Rec call                                                                                                                           
Base c                                                                                                                             
Binary is: 0011
```